# SVG pie-chart working only in Chrome, not in Firefox

Tags: svg, charts, pie-chart

Trying to generate a piechart in SVG. Works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox. Any ideas? The slice is 35% of the pie. Added PI to calculate the slice. I think I've done everything correctly. Tried latest Firefox in both Mac and Windows. Same result. Slice doesn't show up. Had to add calc() to do the right math.

```html
    <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="width: 500px; height: auto;">
        <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="#F2FBFF" />
        <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent" stroke="#21BAFF" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="calc(35 * 31.42 / 100) 31.42" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: don't use calc as a value of stroke-dasharray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox does not support the use of CSS functions in [presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes). You have to use true CSS properties.

In its current state, presentation attributes are fiddly business. Not everything the SVG spec and various CSS specs propose is implemented. Here are a few rules I use to stay on the safe side:

- Never use Geometry properties (x, y, rx, height, ...) as CSS properties. There is not enough support yet.
- `calc()` and other CSS functions can only be used in CSS style rules. Always add units.
- `transform` as an attribute and `transform` as a CSS property are to be considered distinct methods with differing syntax. (Center of transformation, use of units, spacing and comma rules)

Now for your problem, you can use

```
style="stroke-dasharray:calc(35 * 31.42px / 100) 31.42px"
```

but note the use of the `px` unit. Without it, Firefox will fail you.

```html
<svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="width: 500px; height: auto;">
        <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="#F2FBFF" />
        <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" style="fill:transparent;stroke:#21BAFF;stroke-width:10;stroke-dasharray:calc(35 * 31.42px / 100) 31.42px" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" transform="rotate(-90) translate(-20)" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, calc() was the problem here. I handled it via PHP, not via CSS. Not sure if that works better in a cached environment or not.